# Is there a Doppler effect measured on the sunlight depending of the seasonal position of the Earth regarding the motion of the Sun through space?

Tags: astronomy, frequency, relative-motion, doppler-effect

The whole question is mentioned in the title but here I would add the conjecture that I am affraid that the answer(s) should be similar to a possible question about Michelson and Morley experiment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is Doppler shift. There is a transverse Doppler shift because of the tangential motion of the Earth around the Sun. There is also a variable longitudinal Doppler shift caused by the fact that the Earth's orbit is non-circular and there will be a component of the Earth's orbital velocity towards or away from the Sun at different times in the year.